# Choosing AWS service for MQTT broker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I need to build IOT MQTT broker that should work on secure MQTT protocol. I also need to manage users that connects to this service and manage subscription access control. Idon't need MQTT via web socket.

At first glance I was planning to use EC2 service in order to create Ubuntu virtual machine and install Mosquitto service in it. But later I found Internet of Things section that contains set of services.

Is it possible to construct MQTT service according my requirements by using Internet of Things. By choosing Internet of Things I hope to get more specialized functionality.

Comment: If you just need an MQTT broker, I think you can use AWS IoT. To deal with the access control, you can deploy some Identity Management system together with a Policy Enforcement Point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS IoT for this instead, they have a managed MQTT endpoint that you can add 'things' to it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html

You'll be able to easily connect the endpoint to other services as this is part of their cloud solutions.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-gs.html